# php getenv('HOME') returns false

Tags: php

When running

```
getenv('HOME');
```

it just returns false. Therefore some scripts ran by

```
shell_exec();
```

don't work, because they are missing the home path.

PHP (5.5) runs on debian, so it should work according to the manual, but why is it empty then?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are doing? Also, are you running your script from the command line?

Comment: Are you running your scripts standalone or via some web server? And also does the user that is running your scripts have home directory at all?

Comment: Yes, the script is ran from a web server and yes, the user does have a home directory

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have found some solution to this problem. But in the interest of others who may drop by, in search of solutions to a similar problem:

I also encountered this sort of issue. In my case it happened in `Windows`, `Apache`, `PHP` stack, but only when I configure `PHP` to run with `mod_fcgid`. In that case, variables that I knew existed in the OS environment refused to appear with PHP `getenv()`, with the exception of few.

My solution: I added this to `httpd.conf`:

PassEnv HOME